# SQL- How to select data from two different table?

Tags: sql

I am working to select data from 2 different table but I can't figured out. If I use INNER JOIN it show noting. Any help are welcome and Thanks.

My First table:

```
CREATE TABLE P_N( 
PN_ID int NOT NULL,
PN VARCHAR (1000),
primary key (PN_ID)
);
```

My second Table:

```
CREATE TABLE NAME (
NAME_ID VARCHAR(60) PRIMARY key,
NAME  VARCHAR (40)
);
```

My select code :

```
SELECT DISTINCT NAME.NAME_ID,  PN.PN_ID
FROM NAME
FULL JOIN P_N 
ON PN.PN =NAME.NAME_ID;
```

If I use left or full Join this is the result:

```
NAME_ID      PN_ID
nm0006300    NULL
nm0006400    NULL
nm0006500    NULL
nm0006600    NULL
nm0006700    NULL
```

AND if I use right join:

```
NAME_ID      PN_ID
null        921691
null        921692
null        921693
null        921694
```

This is what I want the result to looks like For example:

```
NAME_ID        PN_ID
nm0006300      921691
nm0006400      921692
nm0006500      921693
nm0006600      921694
```

Comment: You have no matching data on your key.  Sample data would help.

Comment: So how do I added or select the matching data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to have a `JOIN` key.  You can add one with `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT n.NAME_ID, PN.PN_ID
FROM (SELECT n.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NAME_ID) as seqnum
      FROM NAME n
     ) n JOIN
     (SELECT pn.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PN) as seqnum
      FROM P_N pn
     ) pn
     ON PN.seqnum = n.seqnum;
```

Comment: So in the ROW_NUMBER() do I need to add the row number For example ROW_NUMBER(1) ?

Comment: @Omar . . . No.  `ROW_NUMBER()` does not take an argument.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select DISTINCT NAME.NAME_ID,  PN.PN_ID
from NAME,P_N as PN
where PN.PN =NAME.NAME_ID
```

Comment: You have no matching data on your key

Comment: oh SO is there any SQL code that will show both columns ? and thank you